# ELF counterpart for IDA Pro PE utilities

Tags: ida, elf, patching

I'm interested in patching ELF files using IDA and the following [PE utilities](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/pe_scripts.zip) have proven very useful for patching PEs.

Does anyone know if there are some publicly available IDA scripts similar to Atli Mar Gudmundsson's set of PE utilities, but for ELF binaries instead of PEs? It doesn't matter if they are IDC or IDAPython.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you should consider using [Hiew](http://www.hiew.ru/files/hiew32demo.zip) for this kind of purposes.

Since no one offered any solutions, I'll share the [site](http://pythonarsenal.dsecrg.ru/), which represents a large number of python scripts for almost any task, so maybe one of them will be helpful.